# get property form an object in a collection (VBA)

Tags: vba

I create a collection of custom class objects, I am able to retrieve all the object property except for amount property (which is an array)

the following is my code

```
Sub Ledger()

Dim ActPeriod As Long
Dim ForcastPeriod As Long
Dim sth As Worksheet
Dim Account As New ClsAccount
Dim allaccounts As New Collection
ActPeriod = 3
ForecastPeriod = 3

For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("A4:A26").count
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) <> 0 Then
counter = counter + 1
Set Account = New ClsAccount
With Account
     .Code = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
     .Name = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
     .amount = Sheet1.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 2 + ActPeriod))
     allaccounts.add Account, .Code
End With
End If
Next i

MsgBox allaccounts(3).amount(1, 1)


End Sub
```

the code I used to create the class is as follow

```
Private AccAmount As Variant
Private AccGrowth As Variant
Private AccName As String
Private AccCode As String


Property Let amount(amt As Variant)
   AccAmount = amt
End Property

Property Get amount() As Variant
   amount = AccAmount
End Property

Property Let Name(n As String)
   AccName = n
End Property

Property Get Name() As String
   Name = AccName
End Property


Property Let Code(c As String)
   AccCode = c
End Property

Property Get Code() As String
   Code = AccCode
End Property
```

I am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MsgBox allaccounts(3).amount()(1, 1)
```

Without the parentheses VBA thinks you're trying to pass `1, 1` to the Property Get procedure, and that's not defined with any parameters...

Comment: I had no idea you could use parentheses as shorthand to turn Ranges into arrays of values. I just tested it out and `MyRange()` turns what would be a Range Object into an array of Variant values. The same as what you would get from `MyRange.Value`.

Comment: @Toddleson - that's not what's going on here.  The class member `AccAmount` is already a variant array - the additional `()` just make sure it's returned from the `amount` property *before* the `(1,1)` is then applied to it.  Without the `()` the `(1,1)` get passed as arguments to `amount`, which isn't expecting any arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!